How can I automate the connection to an On Prem Windows VM that uses Azure AAD for authentication?
My requirement is to automate the transfer of files, and running commands on the Windows VM, which is currently a manual process where I log in to the VM via RDP (and it prompts me for my username/password of my account).
I have been doing a bit of digging on this, as I am able to automate the same thing for a Linux VM where no such AAD based authentication exists and I use the paramiko library to transfer content from my PC to the VM and run bash commands.
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# Connect to the server
try:
    client.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
    
    # Initialize the SFTP client
    sftp = client.open_sftp()
    
    # Transfer the file
    sftp.put(local_file_path, remote_file_path)
    print(f"File {local_file_path} has been transferred to {remote_file_path} on the remote server.")
    _stdin, _stdout,_stderr = client.exec_command("ls random*")

(Omitted content for brevity and confidentiality)
However, getting a set of credentials to log in to the Windows VM isn't allowed as per the org policy.
I am not really able to find any online resources on the same, beyond this and this but in the latter, it seems all be related to a simpler scenario where there is a username/password combination. I am investigating the usage of Pywinauto to try this out, but I am still not really sure on what the best approach really is. Personally, I would prefer to use Python but I am amenable to any solution at this point (or at least being pointed in the right direction).

Can you clarify what you can and cannot do, and from/to what kind of devices? Those same AAD credentials can be used for SMB file shares or WinRM access in certain situations, especially if your devices are both AAD-joined. Does this process need to run without you? If so, you'll need a service account of some sort created anyways, which could define more of what you need. If nothing else, OpenSSH server runs fine on windows too

This process should be able to run without anyone @Cpt.Whale. Service account creation is something I have discussed with the TL, but whether I will get a file or key/value pairs is something I need to figure out. What I can confirm at this moment is that the AAD Cred (for my account) is to be used to for log in. I have a separate service account that is used for authenticating a login for Linux VMs, but the same one cannot be used for logging into a Windows VM.

That by the way was the ideal solution, but I am actually open to anything.

For the OpenSSH thing, we did request for a ticket to open the said ports, but then I am trying to figure out how to automate the auth process.

@Cpt.Whale Please help. Any suggestions would be extremely helpful. As for SSH I found out the Windows VM is not listening for connections on port 22. I have raised a ticket with the IT Team of my client
